# phpthumb is creating the image but not showing it (nginx)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, phpthumb

I'm trying to get phpthumb to work on my wife's wordpress site .
http://downtherabbithole.co.uk/

If you look at the second post the image is not showing.
http://downtherabbithole.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Elegant/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://i.imgur.com/aSFPujD.jpg&h=225&w=647&zc=1&q=100

Is there a way to find out why this is not showing? I run nginx also if this means anything.

Also phpthumb has made the thumb as I can find it in the cache folder. So it is making it fine but will not show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version v1.7.9-200805132119 of phpThumb which I can see when I click your link.

I can also see a whole lot of errors... these errors will be screwing up the header of the image so you need to fix them.

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /srv/www/downtherabbithole.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/Elegant/phpThumb/phpthumb.class.php on line 980

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /srv/www/downtherabbithole.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/Elegant/phpThumb/phpthumb.class.php on line 890

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /srv/www/downtherabbithole.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/Elegant/phpThumb/phpthumb.functions.php on line 886
```

All of the errors seem to be to do with the deperecated ereg* functions... luckily these should all be easily fixed by upgrading your version of phpThumb to the latest version - v1.7.10 fixed this issue you are getting... v1.7.11 is available.

Alternatively if you cannot upgrade phpThumb you could supress the E_DEPRECATED errors in your php.ini... but that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Thank you! unreal all I did was update it lol Thanks so much Matt I would also upvote but I need 15 rep to do so.